# Understanding the Proof of the Hyperplane Separation Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Am reading Wiki's proof of the [Hyperplane Separation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem) and am having trouble with the last part of the proof. Let me give you the structure of the argument and explain precisely where I have problem.

**Theorem.**  Let $A$ and $B$ be two disjoint nonempty convex subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then there exist a nonzero vector $v$ and a real number $c$ such that

$$ \langle x,v\rangle \geq c,{\text{ and }}\langle y,v\rangle \leq c $$
for all $x \in A$ and $y \in B$.

The proof begins with a Lemma, the proof of which I understand:

**Lemma.** Let $K$ be a nonempty closed convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then there exists a unique vector in $K$ of minimum norm (length).

Thus, given disjoint nonempty convex sets $A$, $B$ we can let

$$K=A-B$$

which is nonempty and convex. Hence so is its closure $\bar{K}$. We can therefore apply the Lemma to obtain a vector $v \in \bar{K}$ of minimum norm. One can then show that (see Wiki's article)

$$ \langle z,v\rangle \geq |v|^{2}$$

for all $z  \in K$ or equivalently $\langle x-y,v\rangle \geq |v|^{2}$ for all $x \in A$ and $y \in B$. If $v$ is nonzero we are done because

$$\inf _{x\in A}\langle x,v\rangle \geq |v|^{2}+\sup _{y\in B}\langle y,v\rangle $$ so taking $c=|v|^{2}+\sup _{y\in B}\langle y,v\rangle$ does what is wanted.

Now, the last paragraph of the proof deals with the general case (where $v=0$ is possible) by dividing into two cases.

**Case 1.** We assume that the interior of $K$ is nonempty. The article then reads “ The interior can be exhausted by a nested sequence of nonempty compact convex subsets $K_{1}\subset K_{2}\subset K_{3}\subset \cdots$ ”. I suppose it means we can find such a sequence with $K^\circ=\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} K_n$.

My first question is: **How can I construct such a sequence explicitly?** Since $K^\circ$ is nonempty my idea is to let $K_1=\bar{B}(z_0)$ be a closed ball centered at some $z_0\in K^\circ$ with $\bar{B}(z_0) \subset K$. But I don't know how to define $K_2$ from there...

**Case 2.** The interior of $K$ is empty. The article then reads “The affine set that $K$ spans has dimension less than that of the whole space. Consequently $K$ is contained in some hyperplane $\langle \cdot ,v\rangle =c$ ”.

My second question is : **How can I show that $\text{span}(K)$ has dimension less than $n$?**

I can show that any subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ of dimension less than $n$ is included in a hyperplane of the form $\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \langle x ,v\rangle =0 \}$ for some nonzero vector $v$. Hence in this second this case I believe we have $c=0$. Am I correct?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I think the first lemma itself is non-constructive. Do you know if there is a constructive proof for HST?

Answer (score 2):

That's **two** questions.

The second is the easier one. We know $K$ is convex. If $K$ has $n+1$ affinely independent
points, then $K$ contains the $n$-simplex $S$ they span. But $S$ has non-empty interior
in $\Bbb R^n$, and therefore so has $K$. So every $n+1$ points in $K$ are affinely
dependent, and so the affine hull of $K$ is a proper flat (translate of a linear
subspace) in $\Bbb R^n$.

For the first, you need to prove that $K^\circ$ is convex. This requires a little work.
Now let $A_n$ be the points of $K_n$ at distance $\ge 1/n$ from the complement
of $K^\circ$ (I suppose let $A_n=\Bbb R^n$ if $K=\Bbb R^n$). Then each $A_n$ is closed
and convex. Again this needs some work.

But you wanted an exhaustion by compact sets, not closed sets! Just take a sequence
of compact convex sets $B_1\subset B_2\subset \cdots$ exhausting $\Bbb R^n$
and let $K_n=A_n\cap B_n$.

Comment: Am not familiar with affine space terminology. Can I translate these concepts into vector space terminology? Like replace affinely independent by linearly independent, simplex by convex hull, and affine hull by linear span?

Comment: In fact am not sure why the article mentions affine spaces. The span of $K$ is really a vector space no?

Comment: If you are going to work with convexity, then you **should** get up to speed with affine geometry. @Alphie

Comment: Ok do you know good references for this?

Comment: I believe you mean $A_n$ is the set of points of $K^\circ$ and not $K_n$.

Comment: Am convinced that $A_n$ is closed but I don't see why it must be convex...